# If the jvm gc an unclosed socket instance what would happen to the underlying tcp connection?

Tags: java, sockets, garbage-collection

If there is a unused socket instance, but it is not closed.

If the jvm would gc it?

If yes ,whether the tcp connection would close automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The garbage collection will call `finalize()` which in turn closes the connection.

See `java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl`:

```
   protected void finalize() throws IOException {
        close();
    }
```

Almost like magic.